# while installing mu-editor on linux pop os, i get errors left and right

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mu

**What were you trying to do?**

I was trying to install mu editor on linux using the guide on the website,
**What steps did you take to trigger the issue?**

I simply attempted to type pip3 install mu-editor in the terminal.
**What did you expect to happen?**

I expected mu-editor to be installed normally, and allow me to launch mu-editor from terminal
**What actually happened?**

I got errors "metadata-generation-failed" and "error: subprocess-exited-with-error × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully."

The error says "note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.". Just in case though, i reinstalled pip, and ensured that im running python 3.10.4. I've tried to update everything i see, but it's not working and giving me tons of trouble.
**Operating System Version**

Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS x86_64
**Mu Version**

mu won't install, so idk the version. Latest version that the linux guide installs I suppose
**Other Info**

I've posted this question on stackoverflow, and a user suggested that I "try running with --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures for example pip install pygames --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures" or run this command before doing my installation guide; "sudo apt-get install python-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev libsdl1.2-dev libsmpeg-dev python-numpy subversion libportmidi-dev ffmpeg libswscale-dev libavformat-dev libavcodec-dev libfreetype6-dev Before running your commands"

These didn't work either. step 1. Gave me an error saying couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement pygames.

step 2 said that python-dev was missing and that "the following packages replace it: python2-dev:i386 python2:i386 python2-dev python2 python-dev-is-python3" however, while installing mu-editor again, i get another new error saying "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully." and "error: metadata-generation-failed" AGAIN.
**Editor Log**

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: mu-editor in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.0.3) Requirement already
> satisfied: pyserial==3.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages
> (from mu-editor) (3.4) Requirement already satisfied:
> qscintilla==2.11.4 in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> mu-editor) (2.11.4) Requirement already satisfied: pigpio>=1.40.post1
> in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.78)
> Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.1 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mu-editor) (2.25.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: appdirs>=1.4.3 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.4.4)
> Requirement already satisfied: pyflakes==2.0.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.0.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: gpiozero>=1.4.1 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.6.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: semver>=2.8.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.13.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib==2.2.2 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.2.2)
> Requirement already satisfied: PyQtChart==5.14.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (5.14.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: guizero>=1.1.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (1.3.0)
> Requirement already satisfied: nudatus>=0.0.3 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (0.0.5)
> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow>=5.2.0 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from mu-editor) (9.0.1) Requirement
> already satisfied: pycodestyle==2.4.0 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (2.4.0)
> Collecting pgzero==1.2 Using cached pgzero-1.2-py3-none-any.whl (69
> kB) Collecting pyqt5==5.14.1 Using cached
> PyQt5-5.14.1-5.14.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
> (63.5 MB) Requirement already satisfied: qtconsole==4.3.1 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from mu-editor) (4.3.1)
> Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 Using cached
> python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB) Requirement
> already satisfied: six>=1.10 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from
> matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor) (1.16.0) Requirement already satisfied:
> pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in
> /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor)
> (2.4.7) Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 Using cached
> kiwisolver-1.4.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl
> (1.6 MB) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in
> ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from
> matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor) (1.22.3) Collecting cycler>=0.10 Using
> cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB) Requirement already
> satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from
> matplotlib==2.2.2->mu-editor) (2022.1) Collecting pygame<2.0,>=1.9.2
> Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB) Preparing metadata
> (setup.py) ... error error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1
> ╰─> [12 lines of output]
>
> WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
> Using UNIX configuration...
> /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found   /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found   /bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found   Unable to run
> "sdl-config". Please make sure a development version of SDL is
> installed.
> Hunting dependencies...   WARNING: "sdl-config" failed!   [end of output]
>
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip. error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata. ╰─> See above
> for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.

Comment: is libsdl2-dev installed?

Comment: i installed it rn using [this](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/libsdl2-dev) method. Gave me another error saying "python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully." @stark